# behind proxy error while ionic installation via npm

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
settings.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601

npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "-d" "ionic"

npm ERR! node v4.2.2

npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "-d" "ionic"

npm ERR! node v4.2.2

npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7

npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET

npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself

npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

npm ERR! network

npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the

npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are trying to install **Ionic** on **Windows** over **proxy**. You need to apply below steps.

First, you need to configure **npm** to use **proxy**. On command line execute below commands. (This will create **.npmrc** file on your home directory.)

```
npm config set proxy http://host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://host:port
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Secondly, you need to configure **Ionic** to use proxy to start a project. Define below environment varible on Windows:

```
Varible name: PROXY (capitalized)
Varible value: http://host:port
```

Lastly, if you will add **Android** platform to your project, you need to make proxy configurations to build application too. In order to do that, **create/edit** below file:

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\.gradle\gradle.properties
```

Create/edit **gradle.properties** file as:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=host
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=localhost 

systemProp.https.proxyHost=host
systemProp.https.proxyPort=port
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=localhost
```

Answer (score 3):

```
npm config set <key> <value> [-g|--global]
npm config get <key>
npm config delete <key>
npm config list
npm config edit
npm get <key>
npm set <key> <value> [-g|--global]
```

npmrc.txt will run you can change your link and port

```
proxy =http://proxy.company.com:8080

 https-proxy = http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

[reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config)

Answer (score 1):

Try

**npm cache clean**

If you are running node behind proxy you may want to set http_proxy and https_proxy using below command

**npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080**

**npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080**

Answer (score 1):

Add IONIC_HTTP_PROXY to System variable helped me.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration#using-a-proxy

Environment Variables
The CLI will look for the following environment variables:

IONIC_CONFIG_DIRECTORY: The directory of the global CLI config. Defaults to ~/.ionic.
IONIC_HTTP_PROXY: Set a URL for proxying all CLI requests through. See Using a Proxy.
IONIC_TOKEN: Automatically authenticates with Ionic Appflow.